# Why laravel only write errors to log file?

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel,and set `Log_LEVEL` to `debug`,but I found my app still only wrote errors to log file.
Is this correct?And if I want to write each request and response to log file,what should I do?

Comment: you need to use monolog for custom logs to get store request specific logs

Comment: Thanks,very helpful!